# android-inapp payment - cannot convert from element type Object to String

Tags: android

I'm implementing inapp payment from here :

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

I reach to this point:

```
   int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
if (response == 0) {
   ArrayList<String> responseList
      = skuDetails.getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");

   for (String thisResponse : responseList) {
      JSONObject object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
      String sku = object.getString("productId");
      String price = object.getString("price");
      if (sku.equals("premiumUpgrade")) mPremiumUpgradePrice = price;
      else if (sku.equals("gas")) mGasPrice = price;
   }
}
```

I reach to this point :

```
for (String thisResponse : responseList) {
```

but eclipse gets error , this is the error :

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String
```

What is the problem ? what should I do ? I'm new to android

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change 
this **String thisResponse** to **Object thisResponse**

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
if (response == 0) {
ArrayList<String> responseList = skuDetails.getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");

for (JSONObject thisResponse : responseList) {
  JSONObject object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
  String sku = object.getString("productId");
  String price = object.getString("price");
  if (sku.equals("premiumUpgrade")) mPremiumUpgradePrice = price;
  else if (sku.equals("gas")) mGasPrice = price;
}
}
```

The getSkuDetails function will simply return null for non-existing product ids. So if you don't expect your product list to vary too often or too much, then you could just define a small number of product ids in your app, and skip null values returned by getSkuDetails.

If you want to add a new product, just use the id defined by the next unused slot in the developer console, and your app will list it without updating the app.

Deleting a product can be tricky, because inactive and deleted product ids will still be returned, so you could mark a product deleted using its description field - use a pre-defined constant, like "NOT AVAILABLE" and check for its presence in your app. If a product description equals to this constant, simply skip it and don't list it.

Comment: thanks for the reply , Now it says"annot convert from element type String to JSONObject" on for (JSONObject thisResponse : responseList) {  line . It needs to be jsonObject .

Comment: @johnsmoth can you please post your `responseList` ?